# simple java example to connect cassandra throws exception

Tags: cassandra

wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ClientExamples

I use this code above and edit the ip and port, start cassandra at a linux server, but it goes:

org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

by the way ,you can reshow this situation easily:)

Comment: is the port on the server accessible from where ever you are connecting from?

Comment: what edits did you do?

Comment: I'm sorry ,I know ping is the way to test net,I don't know how to test a port..^_^

Comment: I only edit the 35 line to : TTransport tr = new TFramedTransport(new TSocket("192.168.2.14", 9160));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, test if Cassandra works on port as expected:

```
telnet localhost [port]
```

Comment: I write 'open 192.168.2.14' and it says : can not open , port 9160 ,connect fail .                                                    what should I do with the cassandra side?

Comment: it means the problem exists with you server(Cassandra is not started). Make sure that you started database. Server should accept new TCP connections on specified port and you can check it with telnet.

Comment: but I could log in cassandra by ./cassandra-cli and the jps shows that cassandraDaemon is running

Comment: Are you sure, that cassandra-cli starts when DB starts? Probably these are different services.

Comment: is Cassandra on your local PC installed? 192.168.2.14 is your PC?

Comment: no, my PC is windows , 192.168.2.14 is the server , I run java code from windows to connect linux where I typed bin/cassandra

Comment: by the way , do you have another example which can be sure to run ?

Comment: is it that ./cassandra is the way to start DB?

Comment: it depends on how you've installed it. Find start script on Linux machine and run it, thereafter check that server is started by telnet on linux machine.

Comment: thank you very much ,I found that if the client and server are both in a windows PC ,it can connect

Comment: Probably default configuration lets bound server only to localhost. Check it out and add 192.168.2.14 as bound port.